# Is there a Linux equivalent for Windows "SetEnvironmentVariable" API?

Tags: delphi

I have something like this in my windows compatible code where SetEnvironmentVariable() is used.

```
path := GetEnv('path');
SetEnvironmentVariable('path', PChar(ExtractFileDir(dllName) + ';' + path)); 
Handle := LoadLibrary(PChar(dllName));
SetEnvironmentVariable('path', PChar(path));
if Handle = 0 then begin
  Error := 'LoadLibrary(' + dllName + '): '+SysErrorMessage(GetLastError);
  FreeDll;
  exit
end;`
```

Comment: Just one question - why do you have this code? It's completely unnecessary, AFACIT. If dllName contains a directory, you don't need to include it in the PATH for LoadLibrary to find it. And if it doesn't, then your SetEnvironmentVariable will include an empty directory to the PATH, which will do nothing.

Comment: There is an Linux equivalent to set an environment variable. However, that's not the way you should solve your problem. Not on Linux. Not on Windows. Would you like to know how to fix your problem properly?

Comment: @HeartWare One answer to your question, may not be relevant here, is dependencies.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Good point, David. Hadn't thought of that...

Comment: @DavidHeffernan yes definetly i searched alot and did not found out anything related to 'setEnvironmentvariable' whereas in sysutils i found GetEnvironmentvariable equivalent to windows GetEnvironmentvariable . basically this is a LoadDll function written in delphi which calls the above code.

Comment: The Delphi code is doing wrong even in Windows. Modifying the path environment variable is not how to do this. As for Linux, there is no LoadLibrary function. There are equivalents for shared objects, but the rules are a little different. You need to understand how both platforms handle this before you can implement this. It is a mistake to try to port code from Windows to Linux when the Windows code is doing it wrong, and you don't fully understand what it is doing, and why it is wrong. Again, I urge you to step back and try to understand. Do you want to do that?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Thanks .i also checked this setenv() function but did not found the library it uses. Also i was debugging the windows code which Loads the Dll and as i know Linux uses Shared Objects and not Dll.  i have imported some functions  from .so in Linux but this one includes the dll from path: "C:\WINDOWS\System32\ws2_32.dll".

Comment: @DavidHeffernan And yes i will go back and understand how things are working on both platform and only then i will proceed further. Thanks for the guidance.

Comment: I can't really understand what you are saying there

Comment: @DavidHeffernan just trying to say that i will step back and try to understand how Linux and Windows handle this .

Comment: On Windows, to specify additional paths for `LoadLibrary/Ex()` to look in, you should be using [`SetDllDirectory()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-setdlldirectoryw) or [`AddDllDirectory()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-adddlldirectory), not modifying the `%PATH%` environment at all. But that is usually unnecessary when passing a full path to `LoadLibrary/Ex()`, unless the DLL you are loading has dependencies that are not located in the same folder as the DLL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a Linux equivalent for Windows `SetEnvironmentVariable` API?

Yes, the equivalent function is [`setenv`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/setenv.3.html).

However, as discussed in the comments, this very likely isn't the right way to solve your specific problem, not to mention the fact that even your existing Windows code should not be modifying the `PATH` variable as it does.